# Devise signin stopped working after upgrading devise(2.2.2 -> 3.2.4) and rails(3.2.13 -> 4.1.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just migrated my rails app from

```
Rails3.2.13/devise2.2.2 ---> Rails4.1.0/devise3.2.4
```

I made change in devise.rb

```
config.pepper --> config.secret_key
```

But now I am not able to login in my app using existing password. I have to reset password and after then everything works fine. I think this should be related to encryption done for the password.

What other change I need to do , so that users of my app can use existing password ?

Comment: did you follow the upgrade instructions?

Comment: The password encryption algo might have changed by upgrading devise. try sign up and the signing in from new account. if logged in then devise has changed its encryption algo.